# How the node id is generated in igraph

Tags: igraph

I want to know how the node id is generated. The following is my guess.

```
For a Ncol format file like:
a b
a c
b d
c e
```

The id of the first node in the file would be zero, the id of second node would be 1.

```
node id
a    0
b    1
c    2
d    3
e    4
```

Every time I read the same file, the node id would not change. Right?

Comment: Don't rely on that, it might change in future igraph versions.

Comment: Btw. you can specify the ids to the ncol reader and then you can be sure that they'll be always the same.

Comment: @GaborCsardi Sorry. I do not know what you mean by specifying the ids to the ncol reader. Read_Ncol(f, names=True, weights="if_present", directed=True) I think this function can not specify ids.

Comment: Ah, you are using Python. Indeed it seems that in Python you can't. I thought that this was R.